# How does one configure "Autoscale" to deal with Web instances which have long wait times due to external processes?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, C#, Razor, EF6.1, SQL Azure

I have been doing some load testing using JMeter, and I have found some surprising results.

I have a test of 30 concurrent users, ramping up over 10 secs. The test plan is fairly simple:

1. Login
2. Navigate to page
3. Do query
4. Navigate back
5. Logout

I am using "small" "standard" instances.

I have noticed that web instances may be waiting on external processes, such as databases queries, so the web CPU could be low, but it is still a bottleneck. The CPU could be idling at 40% while waiting for a result set from the DB. So this could also be a reason why the extra instance may not be triggered. Actually this is a real issue. How do you trigger extra instance based on longer wait times? At the moment the only way round this is to have 2 instances up there permanently, or proactively set it up against a schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async calls and you won't have to worry about scaling up.  The waiting threads will be asleep, freeing up resources to handle other users.

If you still see lengthened response times after that it's probably the external process that's choking and in need of being scaled up

Comment: really appreciate this. Another perspective. I am still using MVC3 in this app, and will shortly upgrade. Was async greatly improved in either MVC 4 or 5?

Comment: I guess "async" significantly increases "concurrency" as well. I would say we are aiming at about 100 concurrent users at present, with response time < 2 secs.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that one cannot configure "Autoscale" to scale upwards if a process is taking longer than X ms. If not, then possibly it should be?

Comment: 1) I don't know. 2) The beauty of async is that it allows threads to be used when the would have normally been blocked (say a thread is waiting for results of a database operation, that thread can be reused by some other code while it's waiting), effectively increasing concurrency. 3) Not sure if long response time is the best metric for autoscaling. If CPU and memory usage are low then scaling out is unlikely to increase concurrency since calls are most likely being blocked on external events. However you can suggest the idea here if you like: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-websites